# Comparison of phrases together with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want compare them(into tag`<p>`) together if them are similar remove them, and show other word that not similar. but this code removed `how are you?` beacuse think it is similar `how`, what do i do?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/CCMKu/

```
<span style="display: none;">
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>how</p>
    <p>what</p>
</span>

<div class="remove">
    <p>hello</p>    
    <p>how</p>    
    <p>how are you?</p>
    <p>what</p>
    <p>fine</p>
    <p>hi</p>
</div>



$("span p").each(function () {
    $(".remove p:contains(" + $(this).text() + ")").remove();
});
```

Output is `fine` in case output should be `fine` $ `how are you?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$("span p").each(function () {
    var item=$(this).text();
    $(".remove p").filter(function(){return $(this).text()==item}).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated the fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/CCMKu/3/

```
var input = [];

/*
 * Storing all values
 * in a single array for
 * a faster access
 */
$("span p").each(function () {
    input.push($(this).text());
});

$(".remove p").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    /*
     * Now use the inArray utility
     * function to find duplicates
     *
     * EDIT: Added toLowerCase() to allow
     * case-insensitive matching
     */
    if ($.inArray($this.text().toLowerCase(), input.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        $this.remove();
    }
});
```